# Why can't I upload video to library?

Tags: 2010, file-upload, video

I created a Site Assets library in SharePoint Designer as I need to upload some videos to SP. Most of the are WMV and some are MP4. I have no issues uploading the video, except for one. Its a WMV video but its 620MB, I increased the max upload size for the web application to 750MB but I still can't seem to upload it.

After I browse for the video and click OK nothing happens. The Upload Document window remains open, and I can keep clicking OK but still nothing happens. I can cancel it but there is no way I found to upload this video. Any ideas why I can't upload this video? Its not in the blocked file types and the max upload size limit is 750MB while this video is 620MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against storing such large video files in SharePoint.

Large files are not well supported at the moment. Definitely make sure versions are not enabled otherwise you'll be out of disk space very quickly. SharePoint 2013 with Shredded Storage should help this in the future.

One of the main issues with large files is the HTTP timeout. This is generally set to 20minutes for IIS so if the upload takes longer then your IIS session will timeout and the upload will fail.

SharePoint 2010 does support streaming video directly from a document library (but just because you can doesn't mean you should).

I'd recommend looking at storing video files elsewhere, more optimised for video, such as a Media Server.

If you are wanting to stream files internationally then you could look at storing videos in Azure and pointing to them from SharePoint, then you could get the benefit of their CDNs and people stream the videos from more local datacentres.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to open the Asset library in explorer mode , which is in the ribbon and try to copy/paste the video. May be works.

Comment: I haven't given this a try, but it seems to work buy just clicking OK and then waiting for about 5 minutes. Even though SP doesn't notify the user, it seems to actually upload the video fine, so I guess there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is weird. Turns out that if I click OK and just leave it, in about 5 minutes the video is actulally uploaded. The screen never changes but goes away once the video is uploaded. Is this happening because its such a large file? I would have thought there would a little notification or change of screens so you would know that something is happening rather than just leaving the same screen on. Oh well, seems like its working.